# Making php to work with httpd on Red hat 5 linux

Tags: php, mysql, apache, rhel

i am trying to install php from source on linux.

How can i make it work with my currently active httpd service ? I dont want to install apachectl for the same purpose.

According to the book i am reading There is command given:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php \ 
 --with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config \ 
 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs 

make

make install
```

How can I make the installation of php from source with my httpd service only ? 
my httpd.conf file is in: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf location..

PS: I am new to linux environment.

Any help appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, run on command line:

```
updatedb
locate apxs
```

and than add `apxs` path to `configure`

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php \
--with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config \
--with-apxs2=[full_path]apxs
```

If `updatedb` and `locate` not installed, run `yast` and install the package `findutils-locate`. Afterwards, `updatedb` and `locate` will be on your system.